# How to encrypt and decrypt?

Tags: python, encryption, substitution

In Python3 I must create two functions, substitutionEncrypt and substitutionDecrypt.
substitutionEncrypt must be revised so that it removes all spaces of plain text before being encrypted and that it will generate a cipher key from a password.(Call genKeyFromPass). psw will replace key as a parameter in the function header.

substitutionDecrypt will have two parameters(cipherText, psw)
I have been given the following codes. it should return the original plainText with spaces removed.

Finally, write a top-level function, main. main should (a) use Python’s built-in input function to get a string to encrypt and a password; (b) call substitutionEncrypt to encrypt the input string; (c) print the value returned by substitutionEncrypt; (d) call substitutionDecrypt to convert the value returned by substitutionEncrypt back to
plaintext; (e) print the value returned by substitutionDecrypt.

Note: subEncrypt and subDecrypt will need to call genKeyFromPass, which call removeDupes and removeMatches. I have been given the codes below.

```
defSubstitutionEncrypt(plainText, key):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    plainText = plainText.lower()
    cipherText = " "
    for ch in plainText:
        idx = alphabet.find(ch)
        cipherText = cipherText + key[idx]
    return cipherText

def removeDupes(myString):
    newStr = " "
    for ch in myString:
        if ch not in newStr:
            newStr = newStr + ch
    return newStr

def removeMatches(myString, removeString):
        newStr = " "
        for ch in myString:
            if ch not in removeString:
            newStr = newStr + ch
        return newStr

def genKeyFromPass(password):
    key = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    password = removeDupes(password)
    lastChar = password[-1]
    lastIdx = key.find(lastChar)
    afterString = removeMatches(key[lastIdx+1:], password)
    beforeString = removeMatches(key[:lastIdx], password)
    key = password + afterString + beforeString
    return key
```

From this code I have created:

```
def substitutionEncrypt(plainText, psw):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz "
    newStr = plainText.lower()
    cipherText = " "
    genKeyFromPass(newStr)
    for ch in newStr:
       idx = alphabet.find(ch)
       cipherText = cipherText + genKeyFromPass(psw)[idx]
    return cipherText.replace(" ","")


def genKeyFromPass(psw):
    key = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    psw = removeDupes(psw)
    lastChar = psw[-1]
    lastIdx = key.find(lastChar)
    afterString = removeMatches(key[lastIdx+1:], psw)
    beforeString = removeMatches(key[:lastIdx], psw)
    key = psw + afterString + beforeString
    return key 

def removeDupes(myString):
    newStr = " "
    for ch in myString:
        if ch not in newStr:
            newStr = newStr + ch
    return newStr

def removeMatches(myString, removeString):
    newStr = " "
    for ch in myString:
    if ch not in removeString:
        newStr = newStr + ch
    return newStr



 print(substitutionEncrypt('the quick brown fox', 'ajax'))
```

I get "nukobjdualhqguyhr" as an output. 
The output examples are:

> > > subEncrypt('the quick brown fox', 'ajax')

'qdznrexgjoltkblu'

> > > subDecrypt('qdznrexgjoltkblu', 'ajax')

'thequickbrownfox'

What am I doing wrong with my code? I have been having trouble with calling a value from another function(calling key from genKeyFromPass). Its the line before the return statement in the substitutionEncrypt. Also, how would I go about the substitutionDecrypt? I've gotten this far:

```
def substitutionDecrypt(cipherText, psw):
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    newStr = cipherText.lower()
    plainText = " "
    genKeyFromPass(cipherText)
    for ch in cipherText:
        idx = alphabet.find(ch)
    return plainText.replace(" ","")
```

Comment: You must debug your code. Use the debugger or go "caveman" and add print statements to see what is happening. Examine the intermediate values of `genKeyFromPass`, `removeDupes`, `removeMatches`, `substitutionEncrypt` and other functions, steps and if necessary character by character. Learning to debug is a major portion of coding.